How to handle image_picker error, hot reloads missing and Flutter not showing up in Android Studio emulator?
C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/table.dart:239:22: Error: The method 'createLocalImageConfiguration' isn't defined for the class 'Table'.
 - 'Table' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/table.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/table.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'createLocalImageConfiguration'.
      configuration: createLocalImageConfiguration(context),
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/table.dart:256:25: Error: The method 'createLocalImageConfiguration' isn't defined for the class 'Table'.
 - 'Table' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/table.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/table.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'createLocalImageConfiguration'.
      ..configuration = createLocalImageConfiguration(context)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart:34:37: Error: The method 'getImage' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePicker'.
 - 'ImagePicker' is from 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart' ('/C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker-1.1.2/lib/image_picker.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getImage'.
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                                    
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart:55:19: Error: The getter 'Image' isn't defined for the class '_MyHomePageState'.
 - '_MyHomePageState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'Image'.
                ? Image.file(
                  
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart:80:22: Error: The method 'createLocalImageConfiguration' isn't defined for the class 'DecoratedBox'.
 - 'DecoratedBox' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'createLocalImageConfiguration'.
      configuration: createLocalImageConfiguration(context),
                    
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart:88:25: Error: The method 'createLocalImageConfiguration' isn't defined for the class 'DecoratedBox'.
 - 'DecoratedBox' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/container.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'createLocalImageConfiguration'.
      ..configuration = createLocalImageConfiguration(context)
                        
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image_icon.dart:88:14: Error: The method 'Image' isn't defined for the class 'ImageIcon'.
 - 'ImageIcon' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/image_icon.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image_icon.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Image'.
      child: Image(

